# Iphone SDK Disable Notifications of Another App

Tags: ios, sdk, notifications

I am writing a simple app (For personal use only) that needs to disable the text message notifications.  I am open to how to go about this (disable push notifications of imessage, mute phone, etc.) but everything I read says that apple does not allow an app to modify the user settings.  I know there has to be a way to do this, but I have hit a dead end.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you think you "know there has to be a way to do this"?

Comment: If its for personal use then apple restrictions don't apply. So there may be a private API that does it, there's dumps out there in the internet of all the private iOS APIs and forums for programming on jailbroken devices etc. where people might know more specifics.

Comment: I know that there are apps out there that do this.  I would prefer not to jailbreak my phone.

Answer (score 2):

Apple doesn't allow this though any official SDK methods.

Comment: can someone explain how to do this using private api's?